# Capture error of php "file_get_contents" silently

Tags: php

here is the code :

```
if( false == (file_get_contents($jsonaddress)))
{
    //error
    print ('Error with stream, getting file instead !<br />');
    $jsonaddress = 'listedesodeurs.txt';
} 

else 
{
    //noerror
    print ('Sucessfully GET data from JSON stream<br />');
    $jsoncontent = file_get_contents($jsonaddress);
    $size = file_put_contents('listedesodeurs.txt', $jsoncontent);
    echo ('Making backup of stream in file : '.round(($size/1024),0).' KB <br />');
}
```

When the file_get_contents = true (no error) everything get well
when the file_get_contents = false I juste got THE big error message at screen... i just like to test it, not execute it !

HOW ?

here is the error message :

```
[function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Inappropriate ioctl for device in
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The quick way:

```
if( false == (@file_get_contents($jsonaddress)))
```

'@' suppresses errors.

A potentially better way is to just test:

```
if (! file_exists($jsonaddress)){
```

May well do you what you want (see if you can get get the stream, but simply return false if it fails)... but I'm not sure how well it will work.  (haven't tried that with fopen wrappers recently)

Comment: You are genius !... and fast !

Comment: @ is often considered bad form - so stick with Tim's second example. Depending on how your php.ini is set up, you may need to look at the cURL libraries to get an external file.

Answer (score 4):

You can also check [is_readable()](http://php.net/is_readable) to see if `file_get_contents()` is likely to fail:

```
if(is_readable($jsonaddress)) {
    // noerror
    print ('Sucessfully GET data from JSON stream<br />');
    ... etc
}
else {
    // error
    print ('Error with stream, getting file instead !<br />');
    ... etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a stream context to `file_get_contents`, which allows you finer control over the behavior. In particular, you can use *`ignore_errors`*:

```
$content = file_get_contents(
  $jsonaddress, false, 
  stream_context_create(
    array(
      'http' => array(
        'ignore_errors' => true))));
$ok = preg_replace('/^.*([0-9]{3}).*$/', '$1', $http_response_header[0]) == 200;
```